# extract data from website pandas read_html

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract data from website [URL](https://www.sqimway.com/lte_band.php)

The table has a span tag which is messing the data extraction, the table value is concatenated with the span tag, I want to extract both the cell content and span tag in separate cells, any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.sqimway.com/lte_band.php"

lte_band = pd.read_html(url)

lte_band[0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have pandas 0.24+, you can use [pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index.html) and then map out unique values to each column name.

```
# Set a new DataFrame variable.
df = lte_band[0]

# Note: We will have to sort on the tuple index to retain order.
df.columns = list(map(lambda q: " ".join(sorted(set(q), key = q.index)), df.columns.to_flat_index()))
```

Output of `df.columns`:

```
Index(['Band', 'Name', 'Mode', 'Downlink (MHz) Low Earfcn',
       'Downlink (MHz) Middle Earfcn', 'Downlink (MHz) High Earfcn',
       'BandwidthDL/UL (MHz)', 'Uplink (MHz) Low Earfcn',
       'Uplink (MHz) Middle Earfcn', 'Uplink (MHz) High Earfcn',
       'Duplex spacing(MHz)', 'Geographicalarea', '3GPPrelease',
       'Channel bandwidth (MHz) 1.4', 'Channel bandwidth (MHz) 3',
       'Channel bandwidth (MHz) 5', 'Channel bandwidth (MHz) 10',
       'Channel bandwidth (MHz) 15', 'Channel bandwidth (MHz) 20'],
      dtype='object')
```

Formatted:

```
Band
Name
Mode
Downlink (MHz) Low Earfcn
Downlink (MHz) Middle Earfcn
Downlink (MHz) High Earfcn
BandwidthDL/UL (MHz)
Uplink (MHz) Low Earfcn
Uplink (MHz) Middle Earfcn
Uplink (MHz) High Earfcn
Duplex spacing(MHz)
Geographicalarea
3GPPrelease
Channel bandwidth (MHz) 1.4
Channel bandwidth (MHz) 3
Channel bandwidth (MHz) 5
Channel bandwidth (MHz) 10
Channel bandwidth (MHz) 15
Channel bandwidth (MHz) 20
```